# HTML input type "tel" attribute "autocomplete" stuck with "tel-national" regardless of the actual value

Tags: html, autocomplete

I have `<input type="tel" autocomplete="tel">` which in some places auto-completes correctly international phone number (eg. +358 44 1234567) and some places to national number.

When it's stuck with national format it doesn't matter which `autocomplete` "tel-..." value I use ([list of values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#values)), it always offers me prefill as the value was "tel-national". When it's not stuck, also changing value to something else works.

In my solution even though HTML is the same issue occurs only in certain environment (production) and works in other (local machine). `autocomplete` attribute is not being modified JavaScript.

How to make `autocomplete="tel"` work as in first example below.

### Examples

Works fine in http://catamphetamine.github.io/react-phone-number-input/
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU7Ab.png)

Doesn't work in https://greenido.github.io/Product-Site-101/form-cc-example.html [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rsXr.png)

### Environment

Chrome Version 91.0.4472.77 (Official Build) (32-bit)